# Convert 3gp files to Ogg Vorbis?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, 3gp, oggvorbis

I have a Xamarin.Android project that records audio to the `.3gp` format using the MediaRecorder. I need to convert this file to the `.ogg` Ogg Vorbis format.

Is there a library or NuGet package that does this already? If not, what would be the best approach for writing a converter (note: I've never written an audio converter in my life)?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** implementation needs to be cross-platform.

Comment: Have seen ffmpeg?

Comment: Have you tried [.NET Ogg Vorbis Encoder](https://github.com/SteveLillis/.NET-Ogg-Vorbis-Encoder)?